# Authenticating a User in android (Hard Coded)

Tags: android

I am  new to android.. Have learnt a few properties.. Trying to authenticate a user by comparing the entered string to a static , hard coded string . I am setting the text of the "Login" button to post the message as "Correct Password" or "Incorrect Password!" , but every time the "Incorrect Password!" message is only printed on the button.

Here's the code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername;
EditText etPassword;
TextView tvUname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

and here is the OnClick method's code!

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String uname = "abhi";
    String pass = "test";

    if(uname == etUsername.getText().toString() && pass == etPassword.getText().toString()){
            btnLogin.setText("Correct Password!");
        }
    else{
        btnLogin.setText("Incorrect Password!");
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help me ..!

Comment: Just use equals while comparing. '==' can be used only whit primitive types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare `String` use `equals`

You compare `int, double, float, long and boolean` with `==`

Comment: is this correct :  uname.equals(etUsername.getText().toString()) ?

Comment: == operator is overloaded in the String class

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Glad it worked. Accept the answer also!

Comment: I ll accept it in 2 minutes.. The counter doesn't allow to accept it within 8 minuttes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(  (uname == etUsername.getText().toString() ) && ( pass == etPassword.getText().toString() )){
        btnLogin.setText("Correct Password!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android luckily has [TextUtils.equals()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) for text comparison

So you can do:

```
private boolean isAutheticated(CharSequence username, CharSequence password) {

    String uname = "abhi";
    String pass = "test";

    //Check if they match and return the result
    return TextUtils.equals(uname, username) && TextUtils.equals(pass, password);
}

@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(isAuthenticated(etUsername.getText(), etPassword.getText())) {
        btnLogin.setText("Correct Password!"); 
    } else {
        btnLogin.setText("Incorrect Password!"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @jedikv , i could use such a authentication method in my project.. :) Thanks a lott..